# How to implement web-socket programing in restful web-services for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to implement web-socket in my ruby on rails application. For that purpose i tried some libraries, [Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye) works in most promising way for my web application but i am unable to use it in web-services where ios and android are as a client.  I am confused about how could implement handshake between rails and ios.

Is there are other ways to implement it as-like **push notification** ?

Comment: what do u mean "ios" and "android" as client. any platform using ur service will be addressed as client.

Comment: yes absolutely, basically i want to know how it works in web-services.

Comment: You can always check out the Faye documentation and associated web resource to study about push notifications. Implementing requires a decent understanding of Rails. Start coding a simple project where two users can receive and send messages without real-time support. Then scale to add whatever you feel like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ankit :Where exactly you want to use web socket programming , Please have a [Look](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-ruby)

Comment: While we are talking to implement web-socket using ruby, I think Pusher is not an option, that will works just like 3rd party API.
However in rails-5 we can do real time websockets  with using Action Cable .